# getChild of body of gmail email using Goole Apps Scripts (GAS)

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

**Problem**

I have automated emails coming to me with particular client details in them. I have the repetitive task of repling to each email with a template. I am wanting to automate the process utilising Google Apps Scripts.

[image: Example Inbox Email]

**Where I'm up to**

I have worked out how to collect the body of the email I am replying to. I'm trying to get the third paragraph info and store this in a variable.

Here is my code:

```
function autoReply() {

//Capturing the automated email  
var queryInbox = "is:unread from:(example@gmail.com)";
var locatedEmail = GmailApp.search(queryInbox);

for (var i in locatedEmail){
  var thread = locatedEmail[i];
  var messages = thread.getMessages();
  var msgBody = messages[i].getBody();
  var clientsEmail = msgBody.getChild('p')[3]; //Attempting to obtain the third paragraph of the body.
  
  if(messages.length === 1) { 
    var body = "<p> The clients email is: " + clientsEmail + "</p>";
  };

  var options = { name: "Temp Name",htmlBody: body };
  thread.reply(body, options);
  thread.markRead();
  thread.moveToArchive();
    
  }
};
```

Note: Img attached for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When the thread has one message, you want to retrieve the body of email.
- You want to retrieve the 3rd paragraph from the message of email.
- You want to reply the message including the retrieved 3rd paragraph.

#### Modification points:

- At `for (var i in unread){`, I thought that you might use `locatedEmail`.
- When you want to reply the message with `messages.length === 1`, `var msgBody = messages[i].getBody();` is required to be modified. Because in your for loop, the index `i` is used for `var thread = locatedEmail[i];` and `var msgBody = messages[i].getBody();`.
- In your case, I think that `getPlainBody()` instead of `getBody()` might be suitable.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function autoReply() {
  var queryInbox = "is:unread from:(example@gmail.com)";
  var locatedEmail = GmailApp.search(queryInbox);
  locatedEmail.forEach(thread => {
    var messages = thread.getMessages();
    if (messages.length === 1) {
      var msgBody = messages[0].getPlainBody();
      var clientsEmail = msgBody.split("\n")[2];  // Here, the 3rd paragraph is retrieved.
      var body = "<p> The clients email is: " + clientsEmail + "</p>";
      var options = { name: "Temp Name",htmlBody: body };
      thread.reply(body, options);
      thread.markRead();
      thread.moveToArchive();
    }
  });
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getPlainBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getplainbody)

Comment: Thank you it works beautifully.

You are correct about point 1 I edited some names to create the example and failed to match them back correctly.

Comment: @Bjaeg Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `You are correct about point 1 I edited some names to create the example and failed to match them back correctly.`. Can I ask you about the detail of the issue of my answer? I would like to correctly understand about it and think of the modification point.

Comment: @Bjaeg Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Comment: Hello! Your answers helped me in my project, thanks for that. Would there be a way to get everything from first to seventh paragraph, instead of getting only one paragraph? I tried to replace 'split("\n")[7]' with 'split("\n")[0,7]' but the result is the same.

Comment: @user10879705 About your question of `Would there be a way to get everything from first to seventh paragraph, instead of getting only one paragraph? I tried to replace 'split("\n")[7]' with 'split("\n")[0,7]' but the result is the same.`, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. So, can you post it as new question by including more information? It will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Tanaike I have created a topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71940507/retrieve-all-content-before-split
I hope it is clear enough!

Comment: @user10879705 Thank you for your response. I posted an answer to your question. Could you please confirm it?