# Retrieve all content before split

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to forward an email and add a paragraph after the 6th paragraph in the original message which looks like this:

```
p1
p2 
p3
p4
p5
p6
p7
p8
p9
```

I have this script (only part of it is shown below):

```
var body = messages[j].getPlainBody();
var firstpart = body.split("\n")[7,8,9]);
var secondpart = body.split("\n")[1,2,3,4,5,6]);
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject, '', {htmlBody: "blabla" + body});
```

Instead of this, I would like to have something like that:

```
var body = messages[j].getPlainBody();
var firstpart = body.split("\n")[7,8,9]);
var secondpart = body.split("\n")[1,2,3,4,5,6]);
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject, '', {htmlBody: firstpart + "blabla" + secondpart});
```

This does not work, as the split returns only one paragraph. Is there a way to include all first 6 paragraphs and all last paragraphs in variables?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to insert a value of `"blabla"` in the text of `body`.
- From your script of `Instead of this, I would like to have something like that:`, you want to achieve the following result.

  ```
    p7
    p8
    p9
    blabla
    p1
    p2
    p3
    p4
    p5
    p6
  ```

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var body = messages[j].getPlainBody();
var p = body.split("\n");
var res = [...p.slice(6, 9), "blabla", ...p.slice(0, 6)].join("\n");
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '', { htmlBody: res });
```

- When this script is run, the above result is obtained.
- If you want to retrieve the following result,

  ```
    p1
    p2
    p3
    p4
    p5
    p6
    blabla
    p7
    p8
    p9
  ```

  - Please modify `var res = [...p.slice(6, 9), "blabla", ...p.slice(0, 6)].join("\n");` as follows.

    ```
      var res = [...p.slice(0, 6), "blabla", ...p.slice(6, 9)].join("\n");
    ```

#### Note:

- In your script, `htmlBody` is used. If you want to use the result value as HTML body, please modify `join("\n")` to `join("<br>")`.
- As an additional information, if your value of `body` is more than 9 paragraphs and you want to include all paragraphs, how about modifying `var res = [...p.slice(6, 9), "blabla", ...p.slice(0, 6)].join("\n");` and `var res = [...p.slice(0, 6), "blabla", ...p.slice(6, 9)].join("\n");` as follows?

  - `var res = [...p.slice(6), "blabla", ...p.slice(0, 6)].join("\n");`
  - `var res = [...p.slice(0, 6), "blabla", ...p.slice(6)].join("\n");`

### Added:

From your following reply,

> Input: `<br>p1<br>p2<br>p3<br>p4` Output at goal: `<br>p1<br>p2<br>blabla<br>p3<br>p4` Output I actually get: `p1 p2 blabla p3 p4` I miss the `<br>` in my output, but I WANT them.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
var body = "<br>p1<br>p2<br>p3<br>p4";
var p = body.split("<br>");
p.splice(3, 0, "blabla");
var res = p.join("<br>");
console.log(res) // <br>p1<br>p2<br>blabla<br>p3<br>p4
```

- When this script is run to your sample input of `<br>p1<br>p2<br>p3<br>p4`, you can see the sample output value of `<br>p1<br>p2<br>blabla<br>p3<br>p4` you expect.

Comment: Thank you! It works but all the original text is now on one line. Is there a way to keep the line breaks? (I have tried with both /n and <br>).

Comment: @user10879705 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate `It works but all the original text is now on one line. Is there a way to keep the line breaks? (I have tried with both /n and <br>).`. I apologize for this. In order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the sample value of `body`? Because when I tested my proposed script, when `\n` is used as the text body and `<br>` is used as the HTML body, each line is existing. I apologize for this. From your provided sample value. I would like to confirm it.

Comment: This is part of the content from "Gmail / See original message":
`<div dir=3D"ltr">Instrument Name: confidential<br>Version String: 7.0/7.0<br=
>Compilation Date: 16.12.2021<br>ID: 1178187<br>Manufac=
turer ID: 1193907<br>`

Comment: @user10879705 Thank you for replying. Is the value of `<div dir=3D"ltr">Instrument Name: confidential<br>Version String: 7.0/7.0<br= >Compilation Date: 16.12.2021<br>ID: 1178187<br>Manufac= turer ID: 1193907<br>` your sample input value? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output value you expect?

Comment: Indeed. I would like it to be the same output, but this is the output I get in Gmail: 
`Instrument Name: cobas co=
nfindential
Version String: 7.0/7.0
Compilation Date: 16.12.2021
iSDoc ID: 1178187
Schema ID/Manufacturer ID: 1193907`

Comment: @user10879705 Thank you for replying. About `Instrument Name: cobas co= nfindential Version String: 7.0/7.0 Compilation Date: 16.12.2021 iSDoc ID: 1178187 Schema ID/Manufacturer ID: 1193907`, in this case, I cannot understand the line break. In your actual question, you want to retrieve the rendered texts without the tags? I had thought that you wanted to insert `blabla` to the middle of paragraphs. Was my understanding not correct?

Comment: That's indeed what I would like to do, sorry I only copied the content partially, but the blabla is well inserted. The issue is that all <br> disappear in the output.

Comment: @user10879705 Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm your question. You want to convert `<div dir=3D"ltr">Instrument Name: confidential<br>Version String: 7.0/7.0<br= >Compilation Date: 16.12.2021<br>ID: 1178187<br>Manufac= turer ID: 1193907<br>` to `Instrument Name: cobas co= nfindential Version String: 7.0/7.0 Compilation Date: 16.12.2021 iSDoc ID: 1178187 Schema ID/Manufacturer ID: 1193907`. You don't want to insert `blabla` to the text. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No no I do want to insert blabla, like this for example: `<div dir=3D"ltr">Instrument Name: confidential<br>Version String: 7.0/7.0<br= >Compilation Date: 16.12.2021<br>ID: 1178187<br>blabla<br>Manufac= turer ID: 1193907<br>`
This is the result I get with the script (you can see the <br> are not here anymore and all the content is on one line only): 
`Instrument Name: cobas co= nfindential Version String: 7.0/7.0 Compilation Date: 16.12.2021 iSDoc ID: 1178187 blabla Manufacturer ID: 1193907`

Comment: The problem with your script is that all line breaks disappear. The blabla is well inserted though.

Comment: @user10879705 Thank you for replying. About your sample output value of `Instrument Name: cobas co= nfindential Version String: 7.0/7.0 Compilation Date: 16.12.2021 iSDoc ID: 1178187 blabla Manufacturer ID: 1193907, where is the value of `iSDoc` from? I cannot understand the logic for achieving from your sample input to your sample output. I apologize for my poor English skill. And, in your goal, you don't want to use the line break. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @user10879705 And also, if `Instrument Name: cobas co= nfindential Version String: 7.0/7.0 Compilation Date: 16.12.2021 iSDoc ID: 1178187 blabla Manufacturer ID: 1193907` is your expected value, when this value is used as the HTML body. I think that the text becomes one line. So, I cannot understand your actual goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Let's forget all the comments above and simplify. 

Input: <br>p1<br>p2<br>p3<br>p4
Output at goal: <br>p1<br>p2<br>blabla<br>p3<br>p4
Output I actually get: p1 p2 blabla p3 p4

I miss the <br> in my output, but I WANT them. :)

Comment: @user10879705 Thank you for your reply. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I got it finally. The code was good but `getBody()` had to be used instead of `getPlainBody()`. Thank you for all your time!

Comment: @user10879705 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `I got it finally. The code was good but getBody() had to be used instead of getPlainBody(). Thank you for all your time!` and this current situation, I couldn't understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you whether my answer could resolve your issue? If my answer was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: Your first answer was useful yes. It just needed a modification from getPlainBody to getBody.

Comment: @user10879705 Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a regex replacement here:

```js
var input = "p1\np2\np3\np4\np5\np6\np7\np8\np9";
var output = input.replace(/^((?:[\s\S]*?\n){6})/, "$1blabla\n");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Dumb question, but is it possible to replace "p1, p2, p3" etc with the actual content of these paragraphs?

Comment: @user10879705 Not a dumb question, but actually my answer _already_ is doing that.  The first 6 paragraphs are captured in `$1`, and then we replace with `$1` followed by the new content.

Comment: But this is what I get in the console: 
`p1
p2
p3
p4
p5
p6
blabla
p7
p8
p9`
while the text is something else in the original message. Should I keep the split function somewhere? This is my code at the moment:
`var body = messages[j].getPlainBody();
var input = "p1\np2\np3\np4\np5\np6\np7\np8\np9";
var output = input.replace(/^((?:[\s\S]*?\n){6})/, "$1blabla\n");
console.log(output);`